# Using 'connect-pg-simple' npm module and getting error "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:5432" intermittently when the RDS is restarted

Tags: postgresql, express-session

I am using 'connect-pg-simple' npm module for session management for our application hosted on AWS and AWS RDS for storing session details. When the RDS is restarted, the application is unable to connect to it and shows the following error. This issue is intermittent.

```
Failed to prune sessions: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:5432
Failed to prune sessions: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:5432
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:5432
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:5432
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
```

The implementation:

```
let session = require('express-session');

let pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
    const pg = require('pg');
    const sessionPool = new pg.Pool({
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: dbPass,
      database: "bludb",
      max: 100
    });
    let sessionOptions = {
      secret: "secret",
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      store: new pgSession({
        pool: sessionPool,
        ttl: process.env.SESSION_TIMEOUT / 1000,
        createTableIfMissing: true,
        pruneSessionInterval: 1800
      })
    };
    app.use(session(sessionOptions));
```

Can anybody help me with what may be wrong here?

npm module documentation links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-pg-simple

https://github.com/voxpelli/node-connect-pg-simple

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing a similar issue with connect-pg-simple